# Xcode 12.0.1 - No Downloadable Simulators

Tags: xcode

Running Xcode 12.0.1. I need a simulator for iOS 12.x. When going to the "Components" screen there is a header for "Simulator" and "Size" but there are no simulators showing. How can I download an older simulator? I've tried getting to this components screen from "Preferences" as well as through "Devices and Simulators" but again it's blank offering no ability to download any other simulator. I also tried from the iOS 14 simulator directly, but there is no option there to download an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a bug reported by many. It was stated that downloading Xcode directly from Apple versus the Apple Store would fix the problem, but it has not. I downloaded Xcode 12.2 Beta 2 which did resolve the issue so I assume the forthcoming release will solve the problem officially.